# Ответ бота на голосовое сообщение

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как сделать так, чтобы бот отвечал только на голосовое сообщение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы используете CallbackAPI, вот пример фрагмента JSON-запроса к серверу при получении ботом аудиосообщения.

```
"message": {
    "date": 1580535100,
    "from_id": 175494126,
    "id": 279,
    "out": 0,
    "peer_id": 152495136,
    "text": "",
    "conversation_message_id": 512,
    "fwd_messages": [],
    "important": false,
    "random_id": 0,
    "attachments": [
        {
            "type": "audio_message",
            "audio_message": {
                "id": 535462235421,
                "owner_id": 163412596,
                "duration": 3,
                "waveform": [
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0,
                    0
                ],
                "link_ogg": "https://psv4.userapi.com/*audio_link*.ogg",
                "link_mp3": "https://psv4.userapi.com/*audio_link*.mp3",
                "access_key": "25f5c3f2d8cee5d227"
            }
        }
    ],
    "is_hidden": false
},
```

Пусть этот фрагмент JSON вы сохранили в переменную `msg`
Тогда проверка на наличие голосового сообщения выглядит так:

```py
if "attachments" in msg["message"] \
and "audio_message" in msg["message"]["attachments"]:
    pass # do something
```

Если же вы используете LongpollAPI, вам нужно искать документацию по тому модулю, который вы используете.
Скорее всего, проверка на наличие аудиосообщения будет выглядеть подобным образом:

```py
if event.obj.attachments \
and event.obj.attachments.type == "audio_message":
    pass # do something
```

Comment: LongpollAPI выдает такую ошибку:
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'obj'

Comment: @мэрочун "Если же вы используете LongpollAPI, вам нужно искать документацию по тому модулю, который вы используете."
В различных модулях может по-разному реализуется работа с LongPoll. Я писал, исходя из модуля [vk_api](https://github.com/python273/vk_api)

Comment: так я использую модуль vk_api, ничего связанного с event.obj не работает